# Primefaces TabMenu selection is not changing

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I try to build a primefaces TabMenu for a Web-Page.
It is displayed an it will direct my to the Page I want, but it won't set the activeIndex and so it still looks like I'm still on my main-page.

Heres the JSF-View (It's a component, which is inserted into the page):

```
<ui:component>
<div id="navigation">
    <h:form id="navForm">
        <p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{projectCockpit.pageId}">
            <p:menuitem value="Home" url="/mainPage.xhtml"
                actionListener="#{projectCockpit.setPageId(0)}">
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Projekte" url="/projects.xhtml">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="1"
                    target="#{projectCockpit.pageId}" />
            </p:menuitem>
        </p:tabMenu>
    </h:form>
</div>
</ui:component>
```

And here is my Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "projectCockpit")
@SessionScoped
public class projectCockpitBean implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8049539654282700741L;

private int pageId;

@PostConstruct
protected void init(){
    pageId = 0;
}

public int getPageId() {
    return pageId;
}

public void setPageId(int pageId) {
    this.pageId = pageId;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For redirect page with tabMenu, you must use the same code in two page like this.

mainPage.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{param.i}">
            <p:menuitem value="Overview" outcome="/mainPage.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-star">
                <f:param name="i" value="0" />
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Demos" outcome="/projects.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-search">
                <f:param name="i" value="1" />
            </p:menuitem>
        </p:tabMenu>
        //place your mainPage code here
        <p:outputLabel value="mainPage code"/>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

projects.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{param.i}">
            <p:menuitem value="Overview" outcome="/mainPage.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-star">
                <f:param name="i" value="0" />
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Demos" outcome="/projects.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-search">
                <f:param name="i" value="1" />
            </p:menuitem>
        </p:tabMenu>
        //place your projects code here
        <p:outputLabel value="projects code"/>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: I'm using the same code. The main and project page are just <ui:composition>s of a template. And in this template the navigation is inserted...